# yii error active record query

Tags: database, yii2

i'm trying to use yii and i follow a tutorial to simple create a page that shoe fields of database's table.
i create index view

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
?>
<h1>articoli/index</h1>

<p>
   pippo

   <?php
   foreach($posts as $post){?>
       <h1><?php echo $post->autore; ?> </h1>
       <p><?php echo $post->articolo; ?></p>

   }
   ?>
</p>
```

in controllers i create ArticoliController

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class ArticoliController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $posts=Articoli::model()->findall();
        $data['posts']=$posts;
        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }

    public function actionSaluta(){

        $vsa['messaggio']='Alessio';
        return $this->render('saluta',$vsa);
    }

}
```

in model i create Articoli .php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "articoli".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $autore
 * @property string $articolo
 */
class Articoli extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'articoli';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['articolo'], 'required'],
            [['autore'], 'string', 'max' => 55],
            [['articolo'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'autore' => 'Autore',
            'articolo' => 'Articolo',
        ];
    }
}
```

when i try it return

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Class 'app\controllers\Articoli' not found
```

i don't understand. I think that it must go to app\models\Articoli.php

I try different way 
$posts=Articoli::->findall();

but don't work

Comment: Look this guide :  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll()-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 ActiveRecord don't have static function `model()`. To fetch all records from `Articoli` you have to use `findAll()` static method, or `find()->all()`.

Change usage in controller to:

```
$posts = Articoli::findAll();
```

In your controller add `use`:

```
use \app\models\Articoli;
```

---

---

Or just change this line:

```
$posts=Articoli::model()->findall();
```

to this:

```
$posts = \app\models\Articoli::findAll();
```

And that's all! ;)